# Present small ViewController on tabbarcontroller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, microsoft-teams, presentviewcontroller

Im having a tabbarcontroller with more than 5 tabs on it. I tried MS Teams like UI. But unable to present it as a small VC presenting on top of tabbarcontroller.  I tried presenting views on tabbar item click but

1. Unable to fire the tabbar select event on first tap on the button
2. Unable to present over the currently selected view controller
3. Unable to present on top of tabbar controller(view hiding the tabbar)

[image: Intended behaviour:: MS Teams app]

@Microsoft Teams app

Please help me out to implement the same behaviour or comment if u know any library to perform this.

Comment: Hi @vaisakh did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Aiolos](https://github.com/IdeasOnCanvas/Aiolos) project on GitHub. It will allow you to show/interact with panels and you also be able to configure offset in `Panel.Configuratio.magrins`. Another way is to use [custom transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html)